# How do I change the value of a variable in a table?

Tags: javascript

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<!--Variables with Player Data-->
<script type="text/javascript">

    //Player A
    let PlayerAMS = 0
    let PlayerATN = 0

    // Player B
    let PlayerBMS = 0
    let PlayerBTN = 0

    //Player C
    let PlayerCMS = 0
    let PlayerCTN = 0

    //Player D
    let PlayerDMS = 0
    let PlayerDTN = 0

    //Player E
    let PlayerEMS = 0
    let PlayerETN = 0

    //Player F
    let PlayerFMS = 0
    let PlayerFTN = 0

    //Player G
    let PlayerGMS = 0
    let PlayerGTN = 0


    //Player H
    let PlayerHMS = 0
    let PlayerHTN = 0

    //Player I
    let PlayerIMS = 0
    let PlayerITN = 0

    //Player J
    let PlayerJMS = 0
    let PlayerJTN = 0

    //Player K
    let PlayerKMS = 0
    let PlayerKTN = 0

    //Player L
    let PlayerLMS = 0
    let PlayerLTN = 0

    //Player M
    let PlayerMMS = 0
    let PlayerMTN = 0

    //Player N
    let PlayerNMS = 0
    let PlayerNTN = 0

    //Player O
    let PlayerOMS = 0
    let PlayerOTN = 0

    //Player P
    let PlayerPMS = 0
    let PlayerPTN = 0

    //Player Q
    let PlayerQMS = 0
    let PlayerQTN = 0
</script>

<table id="dataTable" border="1">

    <!-- Headers -->
    <tr>
        <th>Player Number</th>
        <th>Missed Serves</th>
        <th>Touched Net</th>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>
            <div contenteditable="true">Player Number Here</div>
        </td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>
            <div contenteditable="true">Player Number Here</div>
        </td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>
            <div contenteditable="true">Player Number Here</div>
        </td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>
            <div contenteditable="true">Player Number Here</div>
        </td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>
            <div contenteditable="true">Player Number Here</div>
        </td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>
            <div contenteditable="true">Player Number Here</div>
        </td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>
            <div contenteditable="true">Player Number Here</div>
        </td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>
            <div contenteditable="true">Player Number Here</div>
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>
            <div contenteditable="true">Player Number Here</div>
        </td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>
            <div contenteditable="true">Player Number Here</div>
        </td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>
            <div contenteditable="true">Player Number Here</div>
        </td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>
            <div contenteditable="true">Player Number Here</div>
        </td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>
            <div contenteditable="true">Player Number Here</div>
        </td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>
            <div contenteditable="true">Player Number Here</div>
        </td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>
            <div contenteditable="true">Player Number Here</div>
        </td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>
            <div contenteditable="true">Player Number Here</div>
        </td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>

</table>

<button type="button" onclick="incrementAMS()">Increment Player 1 MS</button>
<button type="button" onclick="DecrementAMS()">Decrement Player 1 MS</button>
<button class="button" onclick="update()">Update</button>

<script type="text/javascript">


    let array = [[PlayerAMS, PlayerATN],
                 [PlayerBMS, PlayerBTN],
                 [PlayerCMS, PlayerCTN],
                 [PlayerDMS, PlayerDTN],
                 [PlayerEMS, PlayerETN],
                 [PlayerFMS, PlayerFTN],
                 [PlayerGMS, PlayerGTN],
                 [PlayerHMS, PlayerHTN],
                 [PlayerIMS, PlayerITN],
                 [PlayerJMS, PlayerJTN],
                 [PlayerKMS, PlayerKTN],
                 [PlayerLMS, PlayerLTN],
                 [PlayerMMS, PlayerMTN],
                 [PlayerNMS, PlayerNTN],
                 [PlayerOMS, PlayerOTN],
                 [PlayerPMS, PlayerPTN],
                 [PlayerQMS, PlayerQTN],
    ]

    console.log(array)

    table = document.getElementById("dataTable");

    function update() {
        // rows
        for (let i = 1; i < table.rows.length; i++) {
            // cells
            for (let j = 1; j < table.rows[i].cells.length; j++) {
                table.rows[i].cells[j].innerHTML = array[i][j - 1];
            }
        }
    }

    function incrementAMS(){
        PlayerAMS++;
        console.log(PlayerAMS);
    }

    function incrementATN(){
        PlayerATN++;
        console.log(PlayerATN);
    }

    function DecrementAMS(){
        PlayerAMS--;
        console.log(PlayerAMS);
    }

    function DecrementATN(){
        PlayerATN--;
        console.log(PlayerATN);
    }



</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I am making a table where I can just press a button and a specific value inside a cell increases. And the function I have does do that, as evidenced by the value increasing when I check it in the console. However, I can't make it show up in the table, and the value in the cell just stays at 0. How can I make it so the value increases in real time, or after I hit the update button?

Answer (score 0):

Array starts at zero.

```js
table.rows[i].cells[j].innerHTML = array[i-1][j - 1];
```

You're updating the `PlayerAMS` but the array value is being used for display. You can just change the index to update other players. You should also change decrement functions like this.

```js
function incrementAMS(){
    array[0][0]++;
    console.log(array[0][0]);
    update();
}
```

Comment: This is great, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

There are (at least) 2 problems with your code.

1. you are updating PlayerAMS. BUT in javascript the primitive types are not assigned as references, but by value. Meaning that your array is not an array of pointers to PlayerXXX, but an array of values copied at the time of creation. So you need to update array as well.
2. Your indexing is wrong for array (i)

I've modified your update function a bit using your own code style to get the functionality you probably want to get. However, I have to say that it is far from ideal at the moment. Keep working on it :)

```
   function update() {
     array = [[PlayerAMS, PlayerATN],
             [PlayerBMS, PlayerBTN],
             [PlayerCMS, PlayerCTN],
             [PlayerDMS, PlayerDTN],
             [PlayerEMS, PlayerETN],
             [PlayerFMS, PlayerFTN],
             [PlayerGMS, PlayerGTN],
             [PlayerHMS, PlayerHTN],
             [PlayerIMS, PlayerITN],
             [PlayerJMS, PlayerJTN],
             [PlayerKMS, PlayerKTN],
             [PlayerLMS, PlayerLTN],
             [PlayerMMS, PlayerMTN],
             [PlayerNMS, PlayerNTN],
             [PlayerOMS, PlayerOTN],
             [PlayerPMS, PlayerPTN],
             [PlayerQMS, PlayerQTN],
        ]
        // rows
        for (let i = 1; i < table.rows.length; i++) {
          // cells
          for (let j = 1; j < table.rows[i].cells.length; j++) {
            table.rows[i].cells[j].innerHTML = array[i-1][j - 1];
          }
        }
     }
```